# IEnumerable<T> as return type for WCF methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, interface

If i define a Test object, with string and Datetime properties and use it to return IEnumerable(T) collection in WCF

```
[OperationContract]
IEnumerable<Test> GetTestNotes();
```

and when calling the service from the client, I see that it is converting the IEnumerable to Test[]:

```
public Test[] GetTestNotes() {
    return base.Channel.GetTestNotes();
}
```

And Im able to get data.

Question is: How reliable is it to use IEnumerable(T) interface rather than concrete, List(T)?

My clients that consume these WCF services are not only in .NET but also in JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Visual Studio generated service references, you can pick what type is used for collections. Right-click on the service under Service References and select <kbd>Configure Service Reference…</kbd>. You should see these options:

[image: Configure Service Reference]

However, this still won't allow you to select `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want tighter control over what the client interface looks like, your best bet is to define the contracts in a separate assembly and then reference those assemblies on both the client and server.

Comment: Good to know about Configure Service Reference Option. I'm actually wondering if using IEnumerable(T) is going to give me any serialization issues later on. In my simple proof of concept, it worked fine as im using a .Net Client(Console app). But wondering if IEnumerable(T) works with Java Client?

Comment: @sunny24365 Internally, the service uses SOAP (XML) serialization. What type you declare on the interface is purely for the benefit of the client. WCF is smart enough to serialize an `IEnumerable<T>` in the way the service expects.